# I used MPI_Bcast in a loop, but it exited at an uncertain round

Tags: c, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, mpi

Related code:

```
char buf[1024];

for(t = 1; t < 50000; t++){
    if(rank == 0){    
        buf = some value
    }
    MPI_Bcast(buf, 1024, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

After some iteration, it exited. I printed the content of buf, it just showed like this: "^A"

Comment: In cases like this it can be useful to capture the value returned by the call to MPI_Bcast, it might provide useful diagnostic information.

Comment: I doubt `MPI_Bcast` would return anything other than `MPI_SUCCESS` since by default non-I/O errors are fatal and applications are just aborted on error unless the error handler is explicitly changed to `MPI_ERRORS_RETURN`.

Comment: My purpose is to read file in root node line by line then broadcast to other nodes. I did several tests, and found when the length of the lines is big (the length of buf in the code), the content of buf might not be right,  in contrary, the program can get the right result.

Comment: Please show more code. How exactly do you break out of the loop?

Comment: are you try to send `buf` value from all processes to all other processes?

Comment: When you print the contents of `buf`, are you making sure they are null-terminated? I.e. `buf[1023] = '\0';`